# EF7 RC1 : Disable Cascade Delete

Tags: entity-framework-core

In the RC1 of EntityFramework 7, released yesterday, Cascade Delete was added.

To disable it per relationship, I can use :

```
      builder.Entity<Site>().HasOne(e => e.Person)
      .WithMany(x => x.Sites).Metadata.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
```

I want to disable it globally for a DbContext, but I didn't find a way. How can I do ?

Answer (score 28):

Someone stated on the github project forum that the only way to do it right now is to iterate through all relationships in the method `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)`, and set the `DeleteBehavior` property to `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` :

```
        foreach (var relationship in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }
```

Comment: Is .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict) the same as EF6 WillCascadeOnDelete(False)? I ask because I had the DeleteBehavior.Restrict on some of my models yet when I generated DB Schema in SQL Server, I saw that the in Sql the schemas had: ON DELETE CASCADE --> which says to cascade

Answer (score 12):

Right now conventions are not configurable. The current CascadeDelete convention only applies to [*required* relationships](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html?highlight=cascade#required). [Relationships Conventions: Cascade Delete](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html?highlight=cascade#cascade-delete) on efproject.net (Official EF7 docs) You could disable the required relationship explicitly if you understand well the consequences.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Site>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Person)
            .WithMany(b => b.Sites)
            .IsRequired(false);
```

Otherwise (and recommended), you need to set the On Delete behavior explicitly ( as you already discovered).

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Site>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Person)
            .WithMany(b => b.Sites)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```